# Get value text from p:inputText javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I'm trying something simple, just to get the text value inside a `p:inputText` thought Javascript, but I`m not getting it.
Perhaps it's a different procedure with Primefaces, since if I don't use that, I don't encounter the problem.

**My code:**

```
<p:inputText value="any text" widgetVar="youtlink" ></p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton value="Search"    onclick="loadPlayer();" icon="ui-icon-search" />  


<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPlayer() {
        alert(youtlink.text);
    }
</script>
```

I have tried also with JQuery but also no success.

**Rendered view:**

```
<form id="editlFrm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post"
name="editlFrm">
    <input id="editlFrm:j_id_7" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
    type="text" value="assd" name="editlFrm:j_id_7" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false"
    aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
    <button id="editlFrm:j_id_8" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left"
    type="submit" onclick="loadPlayer();;PrimeFaces.ab({source:'editlFrm:j_id_8'});return false;"
    name="editlFrm:j_id_8" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: Your question has also `jQuery` tag, you want solution in it too?

Comment: `jQuery` works with the rendered HTML, so putting your template/server-side doesn't really help. Post some of the rendered source please.

Comment: <form id="editlFrm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  method="post" name="editlFrm">
<input id="editlFrm:j_id_7" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" value="assd" name="editlFrm:j_id_7" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
<button id="editlFrm:j_id_8" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left" type="submit" onclick="loadPlayer();;PrimeFaces.ab({source:'editlFrm:j_id_8'});return false;" name="editlFrm:j_id_8" role="button" aria-disabled="false">

Comment: Adding it to your question through the Edit button is usually more useful. `;)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `id` to your `<p:inputText`

like this

```
<p:inputText id="someID" value="any text" widgetVar="youtlink" ></p:inputText>
```

make sure your form got `prependId="false"`

than access the value like this

```
alert(jQuery('#someID').val());
```

if you don't want to add `prependId="false"` to your form you will have to change the jquery selector from `jQuery('#someID').val()` to `jQuery("[id$='someID']").val()`

---

**EDIT**

since your form called `editlFrm`

try this (make sure to assign *someID* id to your `p:inputText`)

```
alert(jQuery('#editlFrm\\:someID').val());
```

Comment: what do you see when u run this `alert(jQuery('#editlFrm\\:someID').length)` ?

Comment: Ok i manage to do it, Thing is that id and widgetVar should be different.

Comment: NEVER use `prependId="false"` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Answer (score 9):

I came across this question when trying to do something similar, and discovered that PrimeFaces exposes a widget's JQuery element through the `jq` property.

So in your example, you could simply do:

```
function loadPlayer() {
    alert(youtlink.jq.val());
}
```

---

In more recent PrimeFaces versions (since 5.0), exported widgets seem to no longer pollute the global namespace, but need to be accessed using the `PF()` method. The JQuery element can however still be accessed in the same way.

```
function loadPlayer() {
    alert(PF('youtlink').jq.val());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My I think the simplest way:

```
PF('youtlink').jq.val();
```

You can set the value of input field like this:

```
PF('youtlink').jq.val('new value');
```

other way:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets.youtlink.jq.val()
```

and another way if you have ID:

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("yourFormID:youtlink")).val()
```

tested with PF 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Also, there a simple way with javascript:

```
<h:form id="yourID" >
    <p:inputText id="anyID" value="any text" widgetVar="youtlink" ></p:inputText>
</h:form>

function loadPlayer() {
    alert(document.getElementById('yourID:anyID').value);
}
```