# How to get primefaces elements value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, jquery-selectors

I have a primefaces project and I'm facing a problem. I have a simple HTML component which is an `input` element of type `hidden` which gets its `value` from a backend bean. Now I need the `value` of that component as a javascript variable in order to validate it.
How can I access the `value` from the `hidden` `input` element?

Comment: I've edited and rephrased the question, it should be clearer now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558654/get-value-text-from-pinputtext-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the next time, please post what you have tried so far. You can't expect us to write code for you. Show a little bit of effort. But because in that case it is not too much:

If you have something like this

```
<input id="myHiddenComponent" type="hidden" value="something received from your bean" />
```

you can access it with jQuery for example

```
$('input#myHiddenComponent').val();
```

If you dont know the `id`, you can use other [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and the [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as well, pick one which suits you.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I something wrong?