# Primefaces custom positioning for a specific p:growl

Tags: css, primefaces, growl

I am using PrimeFaces 3.3.1. I can customize growls by:

```
.ui-growl {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

But it customizes all growls. I need to customize just one specific `<p:growl>`. I mean, I want to place just one growl to the center and all the rest to the top right corner. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: could you extend the question with some code related to your growl components?

Comment: @akoskm they are ordinary growl components: `<p:growl id="someId" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true"/>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see from the generated HTML the `growl` component isn't holding your actual growl data. The message which is appearing in the corner is hold by a div element:

```
<div id="your_growl_id + _container">
```

so the correct css selector for growl would be:

```
div[id="growlForm1:growlCenter_container"] {}
```

(I assume your growl components are placed into the same form). Finally as you noted in your post if you have two growl components on your page:

```
<h:form id="growlForm1">
    <p:growl id="growlCenter" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
    <p:growl id="growlRight" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  
</h:form>
```

just assign the desired css properties for the centered and not-centered growl containers:

```
div[id="growlForm1:growlRight_container"] {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
}
div[id="growlForm1:growlCenter_container"] {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:40%;
}
```

*Note that you can use the `prependId="false"` attribute of the `<h:form/>`. That would simplify the css selectors.* But it is advised not to use this, see [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render)

Comment: With this solution, components under the growl div will be blocked forever. I dont know why but this is the situation.

Comment: So interesting. After removing height property (only) it works well. Anyway thanks for the solution :)