# PrimeFaces dialog refer to parent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have an xhtml page that display a Datatable with entries. I also have a button to insert a new entry, that displays a dialog that has a form. The insertion form is used as `<ui:include>` in the parent .xhtml as follows:

Parent file

```
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <p:commandButton process="@form" update=":dlgGrp" oncomplete="dlg.show()"/>

        <p:datatable id = "datatable"> 

            various columns
            .....
            .....
        </p:datatable>

    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" >

        <h:panelGroup id="dlgGrp">
            <ui:include src="include.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:dialog>

</ui:composition>
```

Dialog file

```
<ui:composition xmlns . . .>

    <h:form id="subForm">

        various input fields
        ......  
        ......
        <p:commandButton process="@form" update=":mainForm" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>

    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

How can I refer generically to a parent component as show in the file. In a few words as soon as I hit the submit button in the dialog, I want to update the main form and hide the dialog. These components however are in the "parent field".

This should probably be done programatically through the backing bean, since I do not want to include parent-specific actions in the child .xhtml, since I may aslo want to use it as a standalone .xhtml.

Comment: You can consider doing a composite component out of your included xhtml. But there is little information on functionality to give you any further advice.

Comment: This question has completely confused me. The answer does not seem to match whatever is being asked (parameterize the `<ui:include>` so that it's reusable for multiple forms without modifying the include file), yet the answer is been accepted! I'm now not sure anymore what you're concretely asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the `mainForm` through a method in the `backingBean`. Just modify

```
<p:commandButton process="@form" action="#{backingBean.method}" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>
```

and in your `backingBean` do the following ([see Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml)):

```
public void method() {
  // do something
  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.update(":mainForm");
}
```

You just need to check, if your `mainForm` is already in another [NamingContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces/13545099#13545099).
If so, you need to change the `context.update(...)` accordingly.

Furthermore, if you want to update the `mainForm` from your backing bean, I would also recomment hiding the dialog in the `backingBean`, depending on the input processed. If e.g. some data is invalid, you don't want to hide the dialog. That cannot be done currently with your `oncomplete` action which is executed automatically after receiving the response from the server. The dialog would get close whether the input was correct or not.

So add to the `method()`:

```
if (everythingWentFine) {
  context.execute("dlg.hide();");
}
```

and remove the `oncomplete` from your `p:commandButton`.