# Primefaces p:diaolg component not working

Tags: primefaces

i got this error while creating index.xhtml. i'm working with primefaces 3.4 
in my page index ,i will display a list of zones and when i click on the add button ,a dialog window should appear.the error is :
"javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "nZone" referenced from "j_idt10"."

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <h:head>
        <title>Listes des zones</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dot-luv/theme.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="left"  header="Atividades" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <p:commandLink value="Nouvelle Zone" actionListener="#{ZoneController.preparAddZone()}" update="nZone" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"/>
                </h:form>
                <h:outputLink value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">
                    <h:outputText value="Sair"/>
                </h:outputLink>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h1>Listes des zones</h1><br/>
                <br/><br/>
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <p:dataTable id="table" var="zone" value="#{ZoneController.listZones}">
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Zone"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{zone.nomzone}" />
                        </p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Modifier"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{ZoneController.preparEditZone()}" value="Modifier" update="nZone" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"/>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Supprimer"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{ZoneController.DeleteZone}" value="Supprimer"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>

        <p:dialog header="Ajouter Zone" widgetVar="dialogGerLivro"  resizable="false" modal="true" showEffect="slide" width="500">
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <h:panelGrid id="nZone" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                    <h:outputLabel for="titulo" value="Título:" />
                    <h:inputText id="titulo" value="#{ZoneController.zone.nomzone}"/>

                    <p:commandButton update="tabele" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.hide();" actionListener="#{ZoneController.SaveZone}" value="Insérer Zone"/>
                    <p:commandButton update="tabele" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.hide();" actionListener="#{ZoneController.UpdateZone}" value="Modifier Zone"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</ht
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:panelGrid id="nZone" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
```

is inside a `h:form` which is another [NamingContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces/13545099#13545099), where you

```
<p:commandLink value="Nouvelle Zone" actionListener="#{ZoneController.preparAddZone()}" update="nZone" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"/>
```

and

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{ZoneController.preparEditZone()}" value="Modifier" update="nZone" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"/>
```

Try refering to it with `update=":nZone"`. See the link to the other question for more information.

Comment: i did like you say and now i got this exception :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :nZone

Comment: Try naming your form which contains the nZone object, and referencing the object like this: `:formName:nZone`

Comment: IllegalArgumentException? At the component which defines `update=":nZone:"`? The exception sounds strange to me, I'm not sure it origins from there