# JSF ajax Call Error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am getting the following Error:

> Cannot find component with identifier "myForm:display" referenced from "myForm_j_idt32".

my xhtml File :

```
<div id="divScreen" align="center">
  <div id="divPage">
    <ui:insert>
      <ui:include src="/banner.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </ui:insert>

    <h:form id="menuBarForm">
      <div id="menubar_link">
        <p:commandLink value="Home" action="#{loginAct.homeNavigation}" style="color: #ffffff;margin-left: 10px;" ajax="false"></p:commandLink>
        <p:commandLink action="#{loginAct.dologout}" style="color: #ffffff;margin-left: 10px;" value="Logout" ajax="false"></p:commandLink>
      </div>
    </h:form>


    <div id="divMnuAndFrm">                
      <div id="divMnuContnr">
        <h:form id="menuForm">
          <p:menu style="width: 94%;" model="#{authMenuModel.model}"></p:menu>
        </h:form>
      </div>

      <div id="divFrmContnrwithmenu">
        <div style="height: 400px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;width: 100%;">
          <h:form id="myForm">                      
            <p:dataTable 
              var="filem" 
              value="#{fileViewManagementPnation.data}" 
              rowKey="#{filem.ftype}"
              paginator="true" rows="10"
              selection="#{fileViewManagementPnation.selectedFile}"
              selectionMode="single"
              emptyMessage="No Files Found"                                      
                                 >  

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="myForm:display" oncomplete="fileDialog.show()"/> 

            <f:facet name="header">  
              :: File Management ::       
            </f:facet>  

            <p:column sortBy="#{filem.ftype}" filterBy="#{filem.ftype}" headerText="FileType">  
              #{filem.ftype}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Version" sortBy="#{filem.version}">  
              #{filem.version} 
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Size">  
              #{filem.fsize} 
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="File">              
              Action
            </p:column>  
          </p:dataTable>    


          <p:dialog header="File Details" widgetVar="fileDialog" resizable="false" width="400" 
            showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

              <f:facet name="header_det">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/gep_logo.gif" />
              </f:facet>

              <h:outputText value="File Name : " />
              <h:outputText value="#{fileViewManagementPnation.selectedFile.ftype}" id="ftype"/>

              <h:outputText value="Size" />
              <h:outputText value="#{fileViewManagementPnation.selectedFile.fsize}" id="size"/>

              <h:outputText value="File Type :" />
              <h:outputText value="#{fileViewManagementPnation.selectedFile.version}" id="version"/>

            </h:panelGrid>
          </p:dialog>
        </h:form> 
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>     

  <div id="divFooter">
    <p>Developed and Maintained by National Informatics Centre</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying last two weeks to make it work but still am not getting any answers.
Please kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Take your time to put a correct code

Comment: Try `update=":myForm:display"` instead of `update="myForm:display"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `update=":myForm:display"` or `update="display"` instead of `update="myForm:display"`.

Take a look at [NamingContainer in JSF2/Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces/13545099#13545099), it'll give you a bit more background information. It's because `myForm:display` refers to nested NamingContainer within `myForm` which is called `myForm`, but you don't have that. The component you want to update is directly witin the same NamingContainer, namely `myForm`. So simply call one of the above mentioned and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the right component.

You are calling a component withing the same form.

calling `myForm:display` will look for a component with id `myForm` inside the current form `myForm` as in `:myForm:myForm:display` which you do not have.

So you do not need to specify the full qualified name of the form. You can use the id of the component directly as in:

Both components (the calling component, and the called component) are inside the same form so use: `update="display"`

So instead you can either call the component directly as in the example above, or call it using its full qualified name `update =":myForm:display"`