# List of components implementing NamingContainer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, components, naming-containers

I found that there is something called `NamingContainer` in JSF. It is not clear that which component is a naming container. As far as I know, `<h:form>` , `<h:dataTable>` and custom components are naming containers.

Where can I get a list of classes that implement `javax.faces.component.NamingContainer`?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8644762/870122

Comment: thanks, that helps. Although there is an "etc" that i want to resolve

Comment: What is the scope you're searching in? Standard JSF API? Or 3rd party component libraries?

Comment: @BalusC Standard JSF 2.x

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it depends on libraries you include.
simplest way is to use eclipse type hierarchy.

this is mine, and includes jsf RI 2.2, Primefaces 4.0, Omnifaces 1.7 and a couple of self-made:

[image: NamingContainer Type Hierarchy]