# Then Inputtext lost mask when Edit information, what´s wrong?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jquery-inputmask

I need show the mask in InputText field after click in hiperlink for Edit information in my FORM.
When I access the form in first time the inputext fields show me the masks correctly.

Follow my code:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

    <label for="inputcpf">CPF</label>
    <h:inputText class="form-control" required="false" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cpf}" id="inputcpf" requiredMessage="Informe o CPF do cliente." pl:placeholder="Informe o CPF" />        

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#inputcpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    </script>
```

And the EDIT part of code:

```
    <p:column style="width:260px;" headerText="Nome" >
      <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@form" listener="#{clienteBean.preparaAlteracao}">
      <h:commandLink value="#{dados.nome}">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{dados.id}" /> 
      </h:commandLink>
      </f:ajax>                                                                                                 
    </p:column>
```

After clicking on the link the data is loaded in the fields but the field with mask does not display the mask

Comment: Does it instead show the placeholder `Informe o CPF`?

Answer (score 3):

The mask is displayed as soon as you focus the input.
You likely have the input embedded into a `h:form` like this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText ... id="inputcpf" .../>        
</h:form>
```

The `form id` is prepended to the rendered `input id` in client side html:

```
<input id="myForm:inputcpf" ...>
```

Therefore your jQuery selector should look like this:

```
$("#myForm\\:inputcpf")
```

You can find out more about the client id in [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript). If your client id does not contain the id of the parent form as a prefix (or any other [NamingContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389580/list-of-components-implementing-namingcontainer)), then you most likely are using `prependId="false"` which should be prevented of being used for reasons described in [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render)

But the easiest and most stable way to get a masked input in your case would be to use the PrimeFaces component [`<p:inputMask/>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml). Using your current approach the mask is lost as soon as you update the input using AJAX. You'd have to also update the `script` element in order to execute the `mask` function again and have a mask on the updated `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code by primefaces codes. Follow !

```
    <h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden value="#{userBean.user.id}" />
    <p:inputText required="true" value="#{userBean.user.name}" id="inputName" />
    <p:inputMask mask="(99)99999-9999" value="#{userBean.user.phone}" id="inputPhone" >
        <p:keyFilter regEx="/[a-z0-9_]/i"/>
    </p:inputMask>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" update="@form" process="@form" actionListener="#{userBean.saveUser}" />
```

I save the user and refresh all page... The new user is insert in datatable list.
Then I have the dataTable with all users...

Next step I need click in Edit link for edit the informations... and in this moment the data is populated in fields but the **field lost de mask** in input field.

```
    <p:dataTable id="list_users" var="dados" value="#{userBean.allUsers}">
    <p:column>
       <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet> 
       <h:outputText value="#{dados.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
       <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet> 
       <h:outputText value="#{dados.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Ação">
      <f:facet name="header">Ação</f:facet> 
      <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" listener="#{userBean.editUser}">
        <h:commandLink>
          <f:param name="id" value="#{dados.id}" />                                                             
          <h:outputText value="edit" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:ajax>
    </p:column>
    </dataTable>
```