# p:remoteCommand update="@form" does not seem to work on h:inputHidden fields

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The following snippet works:

```
<h:form id="form1">

    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field1}" id="field1"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field2}" id="field2"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field3}" id="field3"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field4}" id="field4"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field5}" id="field5"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field6}" id="field6"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field7}" id="field7"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field8}" id="field8"/>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field9}" id="field9"/>

    <p:remoteCommand name="loadRecord" actionListener="#{bean.loadRecord}" 
        process="@this" 
        update="field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9" />

</h:form>
```

The problem is that when the number of fields to update is large (I have another page with 40 fields) it becomes unmaintainable.

I tried to use instead

```
<p:remoteCommand name="loadRecord" actionListener="#{bean.loadRecord}" 
  process="@this" update="@form" />
```

but the fields are not updated. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

This problem is not restricted to hidden fields, it seems to apply to any input field for example to

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" />
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Which PF version? Sure that you're running the code you think you're running? How does ajax response look like? Perhaps you're nesting forms?

Comment: I'm using PF 3.5. The code runs correctly when the fields are enumerated, but when I replace them with `@form` or `form1` or `:form1` the code does not work. Forms are not nested. Not sure how to look at the ajax response.

Comment: I just tried with PF 5.0 and have the same problem

Comment: Press F12 in a decent browser to get web developer toolset with therein HTTP traffic monitor (usually in "Network" tab/section). Select the ajax request to see the request parameters and response body.

Comment: I just saw the XHR response of the two scenarios. In both cases the input fields are coming populated (inputHidden and inputText fields) but in the @form scenario the response also contains a large chunk of the HTML page, that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: This strongly suggests that you're nesting forms or perhaps has a custom view handler and/or ajax response writer somewhere. Can you please create and post a real [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try reproducing the problem in a blank project with everything set to default unless otherwise specified?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your fields (if they are grouped together) in a [Naming Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces). Then you only have to update the naming container and all it's content will be updated as well. Your `h:form` is already a NamingContainer, but if you do not want to update your whole form you can try this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="myContainer">
  <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field1}" id="field1"/>
  <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field2}" id="field2"/>
  <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field3}" id="field3"/>
  <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field4}" id="field4"/>
  ...
</p:outputPanel>

<p:remoteCommand name="loadRecord" actionListener="#{bean.loadRecord}" 
    process="@this" 
    update="myContainer" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the id of the form you want to update. In your case `update="form1"`

Comment: Nope indeed. It has exactly the same effect as `@form`.