# Primefaces Jsf refresh update the contents of p tab id

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a InputTextarea form where I can save the entered data ,

Also a datatable  where we can see the saved data, and Actions - Edit and Delete the content.

Currently the commandButton **save functionality works fine**.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{gamerCommentsMB.saveNewComment}" process="@this assesmentComments" update="assesmentCommentsTable saveCommentButton assesmentComments" oncomplete="PF('waitSpinner').hide()"/>
```

Request -
But now on click the commandButton  I would like to refresh the tab contents of tab id="assesmentGameFinal which includes textContents.xhtml and  assesmentComments.xhtml something like a browser refresh

So I tried with

```
update="assesmentCommentsTable saveCommentButton assesmentComments assesmentGameFinal"

    render="assesmentGameFinal" 

    process="@this assesmentGameFinal"
```

Did not work, any ideas on how to refresh the whole tab id of tab id id="assesmentGameFinal" upon clicking the p:commandButton?

---

Parent.xhtml

```
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
template="/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="assesmentGameApplication" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <h:panelGroup id="id2">
                <p:tabView id="assesmentGameMain"> 

                    <p:tab id="selectGame" 
                                title="Selection"> 
                                <ui:include src="/jsf/selectGame.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>

                    <p:tab id="assesmentGameFinal" 
                                title="Assesment"> 
                                <ui:include src="/jsf/textContents.xhtml" />
                                <ui:include src="/jsf/assesmentComments.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>

                    </p:tabView>                    

            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>

</ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
```

assesmentComments.xhtml

```
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">


    <p:fieldset toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" legend="Comments">
    <div id="assesmentComments" class="ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-g">

        <div class="ui-g-12"><p:messages for="assesmentCommentsMessageId" showDetail="true" closable="false"><p:autoUpdate/></p:messages></div>

        <div class="ui-g-1"></div> 
        <div class="ui-g-1"><p:outputLabel value="New Comments" rendered="true" /></div>
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <p:row>
                <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="200" counter="assesmentCommentsText" id="assesmentComments"    
                    value="#{gamerCommentsMB.gameCommentsEntity.commentText}" maxlength="1000"
                    counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" validatorMessage="Too long, please limit to 10000 characters" 
                    rendered="true" >
                <f:validateLength maximum="10000" minimum="0" />
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <h:outputText id="assesmentCommentsText" />

            </p:row>   
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-2"></div>

        <div class="ui-g-2"></div>          
        <div class="ui-g-1">
            <p:commandButton id="saveCommentButton" value="Save Comment" type="button" 
                              onclick="PF('waitSpinner').show()" oncomplete="PF('waitSpinner').hide()"                                   
                             widgetVar="saveCommentButtonVar" rendered="true" >
                             <p:ajax listener="#{gamerCommentsMB.saveNewComment}" process="@this assesmentComments" update="assesmentCommentsTable saveCommentButton assesmentComments" oncomplete="PF('waitSpinner').hide()"/>

            </p:commandButton>
        </div>


        <div class="ui-g-9"></div>          
    </div>
    <ui:include src="assesmentCommentsDetail.xhtml" />
</div>
    </p:fieldset>
 </ui:composition>
```

assesmentCommentsDetail.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>

<div id="assesmentCommentsDetailsScreen" class="ui-fluid">
<p:spacer width="10" height="10" />
    <h:panelGrid width="90%">
        <p:dataTable id="assesmentCommentsTable"
                         value="#{gamerCommentsMB.gameCommentsList}"
                var="assesmentCommentsRow" rows="10" widgetVar="assesmentCommentsTableVar"
                selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{gamerCommentsMB.selectGameComments}" 
                rowKey="#{assesmentCommentsRow.commentId}"
                emptyMessage="No Comments found." 
                rowIndexVar="commentIterator">                  

                <p:column style="text-align: center;"                             
                    headerText="Comment Text" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{assesmentCommentsRow.commentText}" >                            
                    </h:outputText>
                    <f:attribute name="rowId" value="#{commentIterator}"  />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="text-align: center; width:5%"                              
                    headerText="Actions" >
                    <p:commandButton id="fileEditCommentButton"  icon="ui-icon-pencil"  type="button" title="Click to Edit the comment"
                                     onclick="PF('assesmentCommentsTableVar').unselectAllRows();"
                                     onkeypress="PF('assesmentCommentsTableVar').unselectAllRows();"
                                     update="assesmentCommentsDetailsScreen">
                         <p:ajax listener="#{gamerCommentsMB.editSelectedComment}" update=":assesmentGameApplication:assesmentGameMain:assesmentComments"/>
                        <f:attribute name="rowId" value="#{commentIterator}"  />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="fileCommentsDeleteButton"  icon="ui-icon-trash" type="button" title="Click to Delete the comment"
                                     onclick="PF('assesmentCommentsTableVar').unselectAllRows();"
                                     onkeypress="PF('assesmentCommentsTableVar').unselectAllRows();"
                                     update="assesmentCommentsDetailsScreen">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{gamerCommentsMB.deleteSelectedCommentConfirmation}" />
                        <f:attribute name="rowId" value="#{commentIterator}"  />                            
                    </p:commandButton>                            
                </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
</div>
 </ui:composition>
```

Representation of the page

```
Selection Tab   Assesment Tab
                Content From textContents.xhtml

                [   Input Text Area     ]

                 ;Save Button;
```

Update - Did not update the datatable as I hit the commandButton button, But when I refreshed my browser the comment was saved in the datatable

Comment: assesmentComments is no JSF element, it's only a div. You can change the div to a `h:panelGroup layout="block" id="assesmentComments">`. assesmentCommentsTable is not present in your code.

Comment: @Holger apologies I have updated the code,

Comment: DataTable is a namingContainer. You can't adress ids outside the table only with their id. Maybe "@form:tableId". If there is a tabView inside the form "@form:tabId:tableId" and so on. You have to look in the browser-source to find the rendered ids

Comment: see all [namingContainers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `p:outputPanel` wrapper and update it:

```
<p:tabView id="assesmentGameMain">

    <p:tab id="selectGame" title="Selection">
        <ui:include src="/jsf/selectGame.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="assesmentGameFinal" title="Assesment">
        <p:outputPanel id="assesmentGameFinalContainer">
            <ui:include src="/jsf/textContents.xhtml" />
            <ui:include src="/jsf/assesmentComments.xhtml" />
        </outputPanel>
    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

I don't understand very well your p:commandButton attributes, but it should be something like this in my opinion:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveCommentButton" value="Save Comment"
    onclick="PF('waitSpinner').show()" oncomplete="PF('waitSpinner').hide()"                                   
    widgetVar="saveCommentButtonVar"
    action="#{gamerCommentsMB.saveNewComment}"
    process="@this assesmentGameFinalContainer"
    update="@([id$=saveCommentButton], [id$=assesmentGameFinalContainer])" />
```

Comment: No, his process and update are ok. The elements only need to be JSF elements and must be present.

Comment: @Blarzek  -------Updated the code with ------------

process="@this assesmentGameFinal" update="assesmentCommentsTable saveCommentButton assesmentGameFinal"   --------
-----also tried with ----------
render="assesmentGameFinal" process="@this assesmentGameFinal" update="assesmentCommentsTable saveCommentButton assesmentGameFinal"

Comment: Received the below warning on clicking the submit button,

WARNING: Can not update component "org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab" with id "assesmentGameApplication:assesmentGameMain:assesmentGameFinal" without a attached renderer. Expression "assesmentGameFinal" referenced from "assesmentGameApplication:assesmentGameMain:saveCommentButton"

Did not update the datatable as I hit the commandButton  button,

But when I refreshed my browser the comment was saved

Comment: Did not update the datatable as I hit the commandButton button, But when I refreshed my browser the comment was saved in the datatable

Comment: Remove your "render" attribute if you have it (don't confuse with rendered attribute). Try replacing all your updates with this syntax update="@([id$=aComponentId], [id$=anotherComponentId])"

Comment: I added p:commandButton code. I don't think you really need a p:ajax for that. Could you try this?