# Find component by ID in JSF

Tags: jsf, uicomponents

I want to find some `UIComponent` from managed bean by the id that I have provided.

I have written the following code:

```
private UIComponent getUIComponent(String id) {  
      return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(id) ;  
}
```

I have defined a `p:inputTextarea` as:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="activityDescription" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.activityDescription}" required="true" maxlength="120"
    autoResize="true" counter="counter" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." cols="80" rows="2" />
```

Now if a call to the method as `getUIComponent("activityDescription")` it is returning `null`, but if I call it as `getUIComponent("adminTabView:activityForm:activityDescription")` then I can get the `org.primefaces.component.inputtextarea.InputTextarea` instance.

Is there any way to get the component with only the id i.e., "activityDescription" not the absolute id i.e., "adminTabView:activityForm:activityDescription"?

Comment: May I know why -1? Isn't it a valid question?

Comment: Perhaps it's just some naive user wandering in `[java]` tag who has no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I notice you are using primefaces. Have you checked ComponentUtils.java ? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.0.M1/org/primefaces/util/ComponentUtils.java#ComponentUtils.findComponent%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%2Cjava.lang.String%29

Comment: @Tapas Bose: A brilliant question that actually cleared my visualisation of UIComponent class. +1 from my side. These kind of questions deserved something more than that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
public UIComponent findComponent(final String id) {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];

    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {     
        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
            if (component != null 
                && id.equals(component.getId())) {
                found[0] = component;
                return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;              
        }
    });

    return found[0];

}
```

This code will find only the first component in the tree with the `id` you pass. You will have to do something custom if there are 2 components with the same name in the tree (this is possible if they are under 2 different naming containers).

Comment: if (component != null && component.getId() != null && component.getId().equals(id))  // get those null checks in

Comment: When compiling against the JSF API, it's not possible to use `FullVisitContext`. It is, however possible, to create a visit context using `VisitContext.createVisitContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())`.

Comment: even with the null checks, this one got itself into an infinite loop for me - so it's not a great solution.

Comment: You check that `component` is not `null`. While in general is a good practise, is it possible that `visitTree` can return a component `null`?

Answer (score 2):

I try this code, and it's help:

```
private static UIComponent getUIComponentOfId(UIComponent root, String id){
    if(root.getId().equals(id)){
        return root;
    }
    if(root.getChildCount() > 0){
        for(UIComponent subUiComponent : root.getChildren()){
                UIComponent returnComponent = getUIComponentOfId(subUiComponent, id);
                if(returnComponent != null){
                    return returnComponent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not possible. The `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(id)` method returns only one `UIComponent`. The ViewRoot is constructed as a tree so if you have two forms in the view, each one with a component with `id="text"`, they will have it's parent components added to the id so they won't conflict. If you put the two `id="text"` components within the same form, you will have `java.lang.IllegalStateException` thrown.

If you want to find all components with the searched id, you could write a method that implements:

```
List<UIComponent> foundComponents = new ArrayList();
for(UIComponent component: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren()) {
    if(component.getId().contains("activityDescription")){
        foundComponents.add(component);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to find the first occurrence:

```
UIComponent foundComponent;
for(UIComponent component: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren()) {
    if(component.getId().contains("activityDescription")){
        foundComponent = component;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's one problem because if you get children from view root there can be another component with chilren and then next inside it and more... You have to use recursion here - no other option I think

Comment: Of course, you're right, it's a tree. I've neglected the data structure.

Comment: Note that the docs on [UIComponent.findComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) hint to a way to search a component by its clientId using invokeOnComponent with a callback.

Comment: @elias I think you answer fits exactly OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in all parent components which are `NamingContainers` you have to add attribute `prependId="false"` - it will works in `<h:form>` for sure and should work in others. 
If it is not possible to set it via attribute in .xhtml file you have to set such value programaticaly.

Suggestion after question's author comment:

If there is not such attribute in components that you are using try write find method like this:

```
private UIComponent findComponent(String id, UIComponent where) {
if (where == null) {
   return null;
}
else if (where.getId().equals(id)) {
   return where;
}
else {
   List<UIComponent> childrenList = where.getChildren();
   if (childrenList == null || childrenList.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
   }
   for (UIComponent child : childrenList) {
      UIComponent result = null;
      result = findComponent(id, child);
      if(result != null) {
         return result;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Next just invoke

```
UIComponent iamLookingFor = findComponent(myId, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot());
```

That will help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In `<h:form/>` there is an attribute `prependId="false"`, but the `<p:tabView/>` doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `prependId="false"` to your form in which this textarea is.

Comment: Terrible advice. Don't do that. Never use `prependId="false"`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid/ It was only (temporarily) introduced to get non-ajax based `j_security_check` forms to work with JSF 1.x anyway. Don't ever use it on JSF 2.x.