# Queue an event before rendering a view in taskflow

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a Task Flow with two views: `listOfClients` and `newClient`. Shown here:

[image: TaskFlow]

`listOfClients` view has a table which I want to sort before rendering it. To do it, I want to create a SortEvent with the table as source (as shown [in the docs, section 29.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-ui-tables.htm#CHDEJAGC) ), but I cannot access the table before rendering the view.

I call the method `queueSortIdEvent` in a pageFlow-scoped managed bean but `findComponent` cannot find the table (returns `null` ). Tried also view-scoped, same result.

My code in the bean is:

```
public UIComponent findComponent(final String id) {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];

    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {     
        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
            if(component.getId().equals(id)){
                found[0] = component;
                return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;              
        }
    });

    return found[0];

}
public void queueSortIdEvent(){
    SortCriterion sc = new SortCriterion("ClientId", true);
    List<SortCriterion> listSC = new ArrayList<>();
    listSC.add(sc);
    SortEvent new = new SortEvent(findComponent("t1"), listSC); // the table id is "t1"
    new.queue();
}
```

**Is there a way to queue the event before rendering the view?**

Note: `findComponent` function works fine in other parts of the code, got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379356/1324984)

My JDeveloper version is 12.1.3

Answer (score 0):

What JDeveloper version are you using?

The findComponent won't work because nothing has been rendered yet. So your component isn't available (= doesn't exists yet) at that moment.

I think there is an easier way to do sorting.
On your page/fragment, go to '*Bindings*', select your iterator (middle column), click on *Edit* (pencil icon) and set the sorting you want in the '*Sort criteria*' tab.

Comment: I edited the question with the version. It's 12.1.3. 

Sadly this doesn't work in my case. When I go back the newly created row is inserted where I had selected before, not sorted