# After adding second composite component Error <f:ajax> contains an unknown id

Tags: ajax, jsf, composite-component

I try to use composite components in my application. When i have added first component it has worked, but when i have added component once again, i have gotten error:

> "javax.servlet.ServletException:  contains an unknown id 'j_idt202:kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion' - cannot locate it in the context of the component searchButton"

This is code of implementation:

```
<cc:interface>
    <!-- properties -->
    <cc:attribute name="isDisabled" type="java.lang.Boolean" /> 
    <cc:attribute name="freeForm" type="java.lang.String" /> 
    <cc:attribute name="houseNum" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="korpusNum" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="flatNum" type="java.lang.String" />

    <cc:attribute name="kladrRegion" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="cbKladrRegion" type="javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu" />
    <cc:attribute name="kladrRegions" type="java.util.List" />

    <cc:attribute name="kladrCity" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="cbKladrCity" type="javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu" />
    <cc:attribute name="kladrCities" type="java.util.List" />

    <cc:attribute name="kladrSearch" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="cbKladrSearch" type="org.icefaces.ace.component.combobox.ComboBox" />
    <cc:attribute name="kladrSearches" type="java.util.List" />

    <!-- methods -->
    <cc:attribute name="listener" 
                  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <cc:attribute name="kladrRegionChange" 
                  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <cc:attribute name="kladrCityChange" 
                  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <cc:attribute name="kladrDlgCloseClick" 
                  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <cc:attribute name="kladrDlgSaveClick" 
                  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <cc:attribute name="searchKladrAction" 
                  method-signature="java.lang.String action(java.lang.String)"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="panelGrid" columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="panelGroup">
            <div class="searchWrap">
                <h:commandLink id="searchButton"
                               disabled="#{cc.attrs.isDisabled}"
                               onclick="openKladrDialog(this, '#{cc.clientId}')">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/search.png" 
                                    alt="#{usertag.labelSearchAddr}" />
                    <f:ajax event="click" 
                            render="kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion"
                            listener="#{cc.attrs.listener}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>

        ...etc.

    </h:panelGrid>

    <!-- dialog -->
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}_kladrDialog">
        <h:panelGrid styleClass="panelGrid" columns="3">            
            <h:outputLabel value="Country" class="outputLabel" for="kladrCountry" />
            <h:panelGroup styleClass="panelGroup"> 
                <ice:inputText disabled="true" value="Russia" 
                               styleClass="ui-inputfield ui-corner-all inputText kladrSearchFormInput kladrSearchFormInputWidth" />    
                <h:inputHidden id="kladrCountry" value="179" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputLabel />

            <h:outputLabel value="Region" class="outputLabel" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion" 
                             value="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegion}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegions}" var="region" 
                               itemLabel="#{region.value}" itemValue="#{region.id}" />                                
                <f:ajax render="@this kladrCity-dctKladrCity" 
                        listener="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegionChange}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            ... etc.
    </div>

</cc:implementation>
```

This is code of tag:

```
<kladr:usertag  isDisabled="#{PolicyBean.policyDisabled}"
                freeForm="#{PolicyBean.policyAuto.holder.baseAddress.freeForm}"
                houseNum="#{PolicyBean.policyAuto.holder.baseAddress.houseNum}"
                korpusNum="#{PolicyBean.policyAuto.holder.baseAddress.korpusNum}"
                flatNum="#{PolicyBean.policyAuto.holder.baseAddress.flatNum}"

                kladrRegion="#{PolicyBean.kladrRegion}"
                cbKladrRegion="#{PolicyBean.cbKladrRegion}"
                kladrRegions="#{PolicyBean.kladrRegions}"

                kladrCity="#{PolicyBean.kladrCity}"
                cbKladrCity="#{PolicyBean.cbKladrCity}"
                kladrCities="#{PolicyBean.kladrCities}"

                kladrSearch="#{PolicyBean.kladrSearch}"
                cbKladrSearch="#{PolicyBean.cbKladrSearch}"
                kladrSearches="#{PolicyBean.kladrSearches}"

                listener="#{PolicyBean.holderKladrDlgOpenClick}"
                kladrRegionChange="#{PolicyBean.kladrRegionChange}"
                kladrCityChange="#{PolicyBean.kladrCityChange}"
                kladrDlgCloseClick="#{PolicyBean.kladrDlgCloseClick}"
                kladrDlgSaveClick="#{PolicyBean.kladrDlgSaveClick}"
                searchKladrAction="#{PolicyBean.kladrSearchClick(PolicyBean.kladrSearch)}" />
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your `<h:selectOneMenu id="kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion">` is in another parent component than your `<h:commandLink id="searchButton" ...`.

It will work correctly, if you specify the correct absolute component id (or move your dialog inside the same parent).

See [Find component by ID in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378437/find-component-by-id-in-jsf) on how to find the correct component id.

The exception tells you that there is not component with id `"kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion"` inside the component `<h:panelGroup>` whid got the generated id `"j_idt202"`.

If you're using PrimeFaces, you can use the EL Function `component('id')` which returns the correct component id. See http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf, chapter 11.2.