# Unable to get component by id in the bean

Tags: jsf

I tried to do in a `ManagedBean`:

```java
UIComponent a = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("a:b");
```

I checked with the chrome browser inspector, and the component has id "a:b". But debugging the code, I get the `UIComponent` equal to `null`.

I tried with all the combinations: ":a:b", ":b", "b", "\\:a\\:b"...

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

UPDATE: I also tried as suggested in the comments:

```java
UIComponent container = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("a");
UIComponent b = ((UIComponentBase) container).findComponent("b");
```

`container` is *not* `null`, but `b` is `null`

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-

Comment: @JasperdeVries I updated the question. Anyway, can you explain why you removed Primefaces and jsf 2 tags?

Comment: The question does not relate to PrimeFaces (it's pure JSF functionality) and not to JSF 2.2 (you are using 2.1 and it can be applied to 2.3 as well, so no need to throw in these versions).

Comment: @JasperdeVries Since I use Primefaces, maybe there's a solution that can be done with Primefaces. And since I use jsf 2, jsf 3 and 4 solutions are not valid. Furthermore people knows I have jsf 2 and not the old JSF 1. Can I put again these tags, please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Is `a` a naming container? What is your (relevant) xhtml structure? When and where do you call this code?

Comment: @BalusC: I know you by fame, but I kindly disagree. I suspect the fact I can't find the element by id is a bug of `Primefaces` 3.4.1. So the tag `Primefaces`, at least, is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved inspired to [Abbas Gadhia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379356/1763602):

```java
public class JsfUtil {
   public static UIComponent findComponent(String id) {
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       UIComponent root = context.getViewRoot();
       UIComponent res = root.findComponent(id);
       return res;
   }
   
   public static UIComponent findSubComponent(final String id, UIComponent container) {
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       
       if (container == null) {
           container = context.getViewRoot();
       }
       
       String idContainer = container.getId();
       
       if (id.equals(idContainer)) {
            return container;
        }
       
       final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];
       VisitContext visitContext = VisitContext.createVisitContext(context);
       
       container.visitTree(visitContext, new VisitCallback() {
           @Override
           public VisitResult visit(
               VisitContext context, 
               UIComponent component
           ) {
               String idComponent = component.getId();
               
               if (id.equals(idComponent)) {
                   found[0] = component;
                   return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
               }
               
               return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
           }
       });
       
       return found[0];
   }
}
```

Usage:

```java
UIComponent container = JsfUtil.findComponent("containerId");
UIComponent element = JsfUtil.findSubComponent("lastPartOfElementId", container);
```