# I can not retrieve the input value of javascript for jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a script that gives automatic address

```
<script src="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.geocomplete.js"> </ script>

<script>
  $ (function () {
    $ ("# geocomplete " ) . geocomplete ( {
      map: , " Give us feedback . "
      details " form ul "
      detailsAttribute " geo - data "
    } ) ;

  } ) ;
```

and the jsf part here is the code!

```
<h:inputText id="geocomplete" style="margin-left:34%" type="text" value="#{creerCompteFacade.adresse}" />
```

but the problem that gives no automatic address

I changed

```
<input type="text" id="geocomplete" style="margin-left:34%" value="#{creerCompteFacade.adresse}" />
```

it works well and gives the automatic address but the problem that I can not retrieve the value

```
An Error Occurred :
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException : Column ' ADDRESS ' can not be null
```

I tried with JSFC but nothing has changed

```
<input jsfc="h:inputText" id="geocomplete" style="margin-left:34%"
    type="text" value="#{creerCompteFacade.adresse}" />
```

Comment: The exception says that you're trying to persist an EJBEntity's object into your database, that has a null column which is adress that cannot be retreived because it doesn't exist. Where's the JSF code ?

Comment: @Omar the problem is that OP's using the wrong id for the `<input type=text />` generated HTML.

Comment: You're right. it seems he was basically missing the `<h:form>` tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         $('input:text[id$="geocomplete"]').geocomplete({
            map: ".map_canvas",
            details: "form",
            country: "FR",
            types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
          });
     });              
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `<h:inputText id="geocomplete">` is inside a `<h:form>`, like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="geocomplete" ... />
</h:form>
```

Thus the generated HTML may be:

```
<form>
    <input id="jsf_65461:geocomplete" type="text" ... />
    <!-- other HTML components... -->
</form>
```

You have two options to solve this:

1. Define an id for your `<h:form>` and then the generated id will be `<formId>:<componentId>`. Example:

   ```
   <h:form id="frmGeo">
       <h:inputText id="geocomplete" ... />
   </h:form>
   ```

   That will generate

   ```
   <form id="frmGeo">
       <input id="frmGeo:geocomplete" type="text" ... />
   </form>
   ```

   Then you can use this id in your JavaScript/jQuery code:

   ```
    $("#frmGeo\\:geocomplete") //the : must be escaped
   ```
2. Use `prependId="false"` in your `<h:form>` so the components inside the form will have the id set in JSF code:

   ```
   <h:form id="frmGeo" prependId="false">
       <h:inputText id="geocomplete" ... />
   </h:form>
   ```

   That will generate

   ```
   <form id="frmGeo">
       <input id="geocomplete" type="text" ... />
   </form>
   ```

   Then you can use this id in your jQuery code:

   ```
    $("#geocomplete")
   ```

   As noted by BalusC, this approach will break the usage of `<f:ajax>` component, specifically for `execute` and `render` attributes. See [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render)

Comment: `prependId="false"` breaks `<f:ajax execute/render>`. It's not recommended to use it.