# p:commandButton can't to update p:panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using PF 5.3, with JSF 2.2

I have a p:commandButton which exists in one of p:column of a p:dataTable. I have a panel outside the dataTable and I want it to be updated once the commandButton is clicked, but this didn't work.

xhtml sample:

```
<h:form id="register_edit_student" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <p:dataTable var="students" value="#{generalPresentation.students}">
    <p:column headerText="Edit">
      <p:commandButton update="updateStudent" value="Edit" action="#{teacherPresentation.assignEditableStudent(students)}" />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

  <p:panel id="updateStudent">
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

My requirement is to update the "updateStudent" p:panel.
Once I ask the p:commandButton to update the panel (update="updateStudent") the page design crashed and all controls disappeared.

I was reading in the internet the commandButton of a column in a dataTable cannot update anything outside the dataTable, **so the question, is there a solution or work around?**

Thanks

Comment: `update=":register_edit_student:updateStudent"` doesn't work either?

Comment: This works, thanks. The page not crushing anymore, but still I couldn't load the new values into the panel.

Comment: Where did you read that a commandButton in a dataTable cannot update anything outside a dataTable? That site should be taken offline for spreading misleading and plain wrong information

Comment: Why did you accept an answer if it still does not work? (Ok, it does not 'crush' anymore, but still updatingdoes not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options to solve this:

1. add `prependId="false"` to your `form`,
2. Prepend the form id in your reference: `update=":register_edit_student:updateStudent"` or
3. move your panel outside of the form element.

Note: The first option should be used rarely and is known to cause issues with plain JSF.

Comment: Some good background information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416770/1725096

Comment: `prependId='false'` has **no** effect in ajax updates. In that case you still need to prepend all id's, so this is not a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: @Kukeltje: This may apply to plain JSF, but could not be replicated regarding the PrimeFaces component p:commandButton. Actually I tried all three proposed options with the given code snippet and two mocks (GeneralPresentation and TeacherPresentation): all three work.

Comment: Hmmm seriously? Need to check that since I'm (almost) 100% sure I noticed the prepend issue with PF to…  but is you say and test that it works, downvote removed

Comment: Hmmmm I can't unless the answer is edited…  weird

Comment: Thanks for looking into this again.