# Updating partial element submits the whole form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ajax-update, remotecommand

I am facing such a problem. I want to refresh one internal element of a `h:form`, a `p:dataList`, and in order to do it I have

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateSet" update="import-statuses-admin-list" process="import-statuses-admin-list"/>
```

Function `updateSet` is called in every 5 seconds. The thing is that, there are some other elements in my form and they are also sent, eg.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{importXmlManagementBean.statusFilter}" id="statusFilter">
```

I'd rather have only this list `p:dataList` submitted, without sending all form.
Is it normal behaviour or I am missing something?

Comment: Your question is confusing and ambiguous. First of all where's the `update` attribute? As the code is now, it shouldn't update anything by default.

Comment: You can use Poll to update your attribute with a specifique time

Comment: Yes, originally I have `<p:remoteCommand name="updateSet" update="import-statuses-admin-list" process="import-statuses-admin-list"/>`

Comment: @YoucefLaidani Update with a certain time interval is not a problem. The thing is the all form is being sent, although only a part of it is specified.

Comment: off-topic: Don't use prependId="false", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: @BalusC: In my humble opinion, the original title, albeit not the best, might contain the words less experienced users search for making it easier to find this and the duplicate

Comment: @Kukeltje: Fair point. I rolled back half.

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for your offtopic remark.

Answer (score -1):

Add to remoteCommand the attribute update with the id of the datalist you want to update, and in the process specify the same.

Comment: Actually I have done that, but whole form keeps updating.

Comment: It appears that you actually meant to say *"but the whole form keeps submitting"* which is quite different.

Comment: Keeps updating the bean...

Comment: Did you try as BalusC pointed in the linked question to mark as partialSubmit="true"?

Comment: It might be owkward to say, but it started working, but as far as I know, nothing in the view xhtml had been changed. But I introduced this attribute to the form.