# Ajax Update on PrimeFaces dialog disables datepicker, and textarea counters

Tags: primefaces, datepicker, dialog, textarea

I have a PrimeFaces dataTable with buttons at the footer for creating, editing and deleting records from the table.

A click on the Create and Edit button displays a modal dialog to carry out each task. During a create or Edit, the dialog is not dismissed but rather an Ajax update is done so that as many record as possible can be inserted or edit can be repeatedly done. But the issue now is, after any Ajax Update datepickers gets disabled and TextArea counters disappears. Code sample is available below:

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{departmentController.retrieveDeptList}" 
                 type="preRenderView"/>            
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>        

<ui:define name="title">
    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDepartmentTitle}" />
</ui:define>       

<ui:define name="mainContent">
    <!--main content start-->
    <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> #{bundle.ListDepartmentMainTableTitle}</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="content-panel">

                        <h:form id="DepartmentListForm">
                            <h:panelGroup id="results" styleClass="table-responsive">                                        
                                <p:spacer width="10"/>

                                <h:outputText id="informationMessage"
                                              value="#{departmentController.infoMessage}"
                                              rendered="#{departmentController.infoMessage ne null}"
                                              styleClass="informationMessage"/>                                            

                                <p:dataTable id="datalist" 
                                             value="#{departmentController.items}" 
                                             var="item"
                                             tableStyleClass="table"
                                             selectionMode="single" 
                                             selection="#{departmentController.newDept}"
                                             paginator="true" 
                                             scrollable="true"  
                                             scrollHeight="250"
                                             rowKey="#{item.deptId}"
                                             rows="10"
                                             rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"                                                     
                                             emptyMessage="No department results found" >

                                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                                            listener="#{departmentController.onRowSelect}"  
                                            update="createButton editButton deleteButton viewMemButton"/>
                                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" 
                                            listener="#{departmentController.onRowUnselect}"
                                            update="createButton editButton deleteButton viewMemButton"/>

                                    <p:column>
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['ListDepartmentTitle_deptName']}"/>
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{item.deptName}"/>         
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column>
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['ListDepartmentTitle_dateEstablished']}"/>
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{item.dateEstablished}">
                                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MMM.yyyy" />
                                        </h:outputText>                                                                           
                                    </p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="footer">

                                        <p:commandButton id="createButton" 
                                                         icon="ui-icon-plus"  
                                                         value="#{bundle['Create']}"                                                              
                                                         actionListener="#{departmentController.prepareCreate}"
                                                         oncomplete="PF('DepartmentCreateDialog').show()"/>

                                        <p:spacer width="10"/>  

                                        <p:commandButton id="editButton" 
                                                         process="@form"
                                                         icon="ui-icon-pencil"                                                              
                                                         value="#{bundle.Edit}"   
                                                         update=":DepartmentEditForm" 
                                                         oncomplete="PF('DepartmentEditDialog').show()"
                                                         disabled="#{departmentController.selectedDept eq null}" />  

                                        <p:spacer width="10"/>

                                        <p:commandButton id="deleteButton"                                                             
                                                         icon="ui-icon-trash" 
                                                         process="@form"
                                                         value="#{bundle.Delete}"                                                                 
                                                         action="#{parishOfficesController.destroy}"
                                                         update=":growl, :DepartmentListForm:results"
                                                         disabled="#{departmentController.selectedDept eq null}">
                                            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" 
                                                       message="Are you sure you want to delete?" 
                                                       icon="ui-icon-alert" /> 
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" 
                                                         showEffect="fade" 
                                                         styleClass="text-center" 
                                                         hideEffect="fade">
                                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" 
                                                             styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                                                             icon="ui-icon-check" />
                                            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" 
                                                             styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                                                             icon="ui-icon-close" />
                                        </p:confirmDialog>

                                        <p:spacer width="30"/>                                                

                                        <p:commandButton id="viewMemButton" 
                                                         value="#{bundle.ViewMembers}" 
                                                         icon="ui-icon-extlink" 
                                                         actionListener="#{dfView.chooseDepartment}"
                                                         disabled="#{departmentController.selectedDept eq null}" >
                                            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" 
                                                    listener="#{dfView.onDeptMemberChosen}" 
                                                    update=":growl" />
                                        </p:commandButton>  

                                    </f:facet> 
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:messages id="messages" styleClass="errorMessage"/> 

                        </h:form>                   

                        <ui:include src="addDept.xhtml"/>                    
                        <ui:include src="editDept.xhtml"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

        </section>
    </section><!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
</ui:define>
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<p:dialog id="DepartmentEditDlg" 
          widgetVar="DepartmentEditDialog" 
          modal="true" 
          resizable="false"
          appendTo="@(body)" 
          closable="false"
          width="400" 
          height="300" 
          header="#{bundle['EditDepartmentTitle']}">

    <h:form id="DepartmentEditForm" prependId="false">            
        <h:panelGroup id="editDisplay">

            <p:messages id="editMsg" globalOnly="true" closable="true">
                <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="500" />
            </p:messages>

            <br/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle.EditDepartmentLabel_deptName}" 
                               for="editDeptName" />
                <h:inputText id="editDeptName" 
                             value="#{departmentController.newDept.deptName}"
                             title="#{bundle.EditParishOfficesTitle_deptName}"
                             required="true" 
                             styleClass="form-control" 
                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditDepartmentRequiredMessage_deptName}"/>
                <h:message id="DeptEditMsg" 
                           styleClass="errorMessage"                                
                           for="editDeptName" 
                           showDetail="true"/> 
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle.EditDepartmentLabel_dateEstablished}" 
                               for="editDateEstablished" />

                <b:datepicker id="editDateEstablished"
                              showButtonPanel="true"                                  
                              change-month="true" 
                              placeholder="Select a Date" 
                              change-year="true"
                              value="#{departmentController.newDept.dateEstablished}"/>                      

            </div>

            <!--
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle.EditDepartmentLabel_dateEstablished}" 
                               for="editDateEstablished" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p:calendar id="editDateEstablished"
                            readonlyInput="true"                                     
                            navigator="true"                                                                     
                            mode="popup" 
                            showButtonPanel="true"                                                                                                            
                            pattern="dd.MMM.yyyy"                                   
                            value="#{departmentController.newDept.dateEstablished}"
                            title="#{bundle.EditDepartmentTitle_dateEstablished}"  
                            showOn="button"/>                                   
            </div>
            -->

            <br/>

            <div class="modal-footer">                        
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{departmentController.update}" 
                                 value="#{bundle.Save}"                                      
                                 update="editDisplay,
                                 :growl, :DepartmentListForm:results,                                          
                                 :DepartmentListForm:messages" />

                <p:spacer width="10"/>

                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}"
                                 process=":DepartmentListForm"
                                 action="#{departmentController.cancel}"                                         
                                 ajax="false"
                                 onclick="DepartmentEditDialog.hide()"
                                 update=":DepartmentListForm:results"
                                 immediate="true" />                      
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<p:dialog id="DepartmentCreateDlg" 
          widgetVar="DepartmentCreateDialog" 
          modal="true" 
          resizable="false"
          appendTo="@(body)" 
          closable="false"
          width="400" 
          height="300"
          header="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentTitle']}"> 

    <h:form id="DepartmentCreateForm" prependId="false">

        <h:panelGroup id="display">
            <p:messages id="createMsg" globalOnly="true" closable="true">
                <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="500" />
            </p:messages>

            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentLabel_deptName']}" 
                               for="deptName" />
                <h:inputText id="deptName" 
                             styleClass="form-control"
                             value="#{departmentController.newDept.deptName}"
                             title="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentTitle_deptName']}" 
                             required="true" 
                             requiredMessage="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentRequiredMessage_deptName']}"/>
                <h:message id="deptNameMsg" 
                           styleClass="errorMessage"                                
                           for="deptName" 
                           showDetail="true"/> 
            </div> 


            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentLabel_dateEstablished']}" 
                               for="dateEstablished" />

                <b:datepicker id="dateEstablished" 
                              showButtonPanel="true"                                  
                              change-month="true" 
                              placeholder="Select a Date" 
                              change-year="true"
                              value="#{departmentController.newDept.dateEstablished}"/>                      

            </div>
           <!-- 
            <div>   
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="labelText" 
                               value="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentLabel_dateEstablished']}" 
                               for="dateEstablished" />                       
            </div>
            <div>
                <p:calendar id="dateEstablished"                                       
                            readonlyInput="true"                                     
                            navigator="true"                                                                     
                            mode="popup" 
                            showButtonPanel="true"
                            showOn="button"                                                                         
                            pattern="dd.MMM.yyyy"
                            value="#{departmentController.newDept.dateEstablished}"
                            title="#{bundle['CreateDepartmentTitle_dateEstablished']}" />

            </div>
            -->

            <br/>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{departmentController.create}"
                                 value="#{bundle.Save}" 
                                 update=":DepartmentListForm:results,
                                 :growl, 
                                 display, 
                                 :DepartmentListForm:messages" /> 

                <p:spacer width="10"/>

                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}"  
                                 process=":DepartmentListForm"
                                 action="#{departmentController.cancel}" 
                                 onclick="DepartmentCreateDialog.hide()"                                         
                                 ajax="false"
                                 update=":DepartmentListForm:results"
                                 immediate="true" />
            </div> 
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: See [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Oh and don't use `prependId="false"`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: @Kkeitje, thanks for the help. I have removed all prependId attributes but the issue still remains the same. Please note that I decided to use BootFaces datepicker thinking it wasw PrimeFaces bug.

Comment: I used Mojarra 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.0, ....I recently added BootFaces 0.9.1 but thats insignificant

Comment: Then remove the bootsfaces component to prevent noise... and still... [mcve]