# Primefaces preview in Eclipse - dialog is too wide

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

my Primefaces form seem to be OK in web-browser (Firefox), anyway in Eclipse internal browser it is too wide (maybe like 4 screens wide).
I dont think that problem is in code, anyway attached.

Eclipse :
[image]

Firefox : 
[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>

<h:head>
<h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>


<br/>
<br/>

    <h:form prependId="false" id="form" styleClass="styleGreen">
    <p:panel id="panel" header="Login" style="width: 400px; position:relative; left:100px">

        <br/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel for="articleCount" value="Count"/>
            <p:inputText id="articleCount" value="#{articleBean.articleCount}" requiered="true" requiredMessage="Enter Count"/>     

            <p:outputLabel for="articleName" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="articleName" value="#{articleBean.articleName}" requiered="true" requiredMessage="Enter Name"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="articleDescription" value="Description"/>
            <p:inputText id="articleDescription" value="#{articleBean.articleDescription}" requiered="true" requiredMessage="Enter Description"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <br/><br/>
        <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-save" action="#{articleBean.save}"/>
        <p:commandButton id="cancelBtn" value="Cancel" action="index"/>             


    </p:panel> 

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Then try using a real browser in eclipse. You can also configure it to use FF, IE or other. Waste of your time to find the cause in an unclear browser  regarding specs compliancy.

Comment: Oh and btw, including the jsf script manually is weird and should never be needed

Comment: And don't use prependId to false http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416770/6546865

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's internal web browser is an epic fail. Don't ever use it if you respect [Web Standards](https://www.w3.org/standards/).

Change it to the external system default web browser.

[image]

Or just don't use *Run on Server* option in the project, but just add the project to the server via *Add/Remove projects* in server's context menu and then start the server and finally manually open the page of interest in your favourite webbrowser, if necessary via a bookmark.