# Change event lost on re-rendering dependent radio button

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Given: one input and one clickable input (e.g. radio button). Change of a re-renders b.

```
<h:form id="rootForm">
    <h:inputText id="a" value="#{fooBB.a}">
        <f:ajax render="a b"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="b" value="#{fooBB.b}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="x" itemLabel="x"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="y" itemLabel="y"/>
        <f:ajax/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

I put the cursor into field A, change the value without submitting, then click on one of the radio buttons that is not the current value (i.e.: generating an additional change event on the selectOneRadio)

Then one of the following happens (possibly depending how fast I release the mouse button):

- a is submitted, change to b is lost (no ajax request for b)
- a is submitted, change to b is lost (ajax request for b having same javax.faces.ViewState as ajax request of a)

In both cases, the mouse click is lost which is very annoying.

Since this is only one form and JSF 2.2, I do not expect this to be some javax.faces.ViewState-not-getting-updated problem (tried most of the workarounds, though).

Using myfaces-2.2.11 (on Wildfly 8.1)

Is there a workaround, did I do something wrong or do I have to live with it?

**edit:** updated example to incorporate Kukeltjes improvement

Comment: Start by **not** using `prependId="false"`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: This did improve the situation: now the backing bean setter actually gets called with updated ViewStateId... but with the old value of the radio button. The click still is lost

Comment: is the behaviour the same in all browsers? And try addijg exlicit events to the ajax tags

Comment: Same in FF+Chrome. Tried using event="valueChange", no effect