# ActionListener method not called from dialog CommandButton

Tags: primefaces

I've this code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  >

    <h:form>
        <h1 class="page-header "> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard</h1>
        <p:outputPanel id="contentPanel">
            <p:commandButton value="Añadir caso de prueba" actionListener="#{testCaseBean.prepareCreateTestCase}" oncomplete="PF('addTestCaseDialog').show();" process="@this" update=":dialog"/>
            <p:dataTable>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Crear caso de prueba" modal="true" id="dialog" widgetVar="addTestCaseDialog" closable="false">
        <h:form id="addTestCaseDialogForm">
            <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="ui-noborder">
                <p:outputLabel for="testCaseName" value="Nombre del caso de prueba:"/>
                <p:inputText id="testCaseName" value="#{testCaseBean.testCase.testCaseName}" required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="assignedTask" value="Tarea relacionada:"/>
                <p:inputText id="assignedTask" value="#{testCaseBean.testCase.assignedTask}" required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="isRegressive" value="Regresivo:" />
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isRegressive" value="#{testCaseBean.testCase.isRegressive}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{testCaseBean.createTestCase}" oncomplete="PF('addTestCaseDialog').hide()" process="addTestCaseDialogForm"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('addTestCaseDialog').hide()" immediate="true" />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

And I'm having a problem: the actionListener method from the dialog commandButton is not being called and I don't know why.
If put this in then commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="# {testCaseBean.createTestCase}" oncomplete="PF('addTestCaseDialog').hide()" process="@this"/>
```

The method is called, but the form is not processed.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also see you have some fields marked as **required**.  If some required fields are not filled up, the validation fails and the action listener is not called.

But if there are no proper **< h:messages>** tags in your pages or templates, the validation errors are not displayed anywhere !!

Ensure you also have a proper **< h:messages>** or **< p:messages>** to show any possible validation errors.

We spend several hours with this issue until we figured it out ...

Comment: It was a validation error that was not displayed. I saw it just before you answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

PrimeFaces provides a partial rendering and view processing feature based on standard JSF 2 APIs 
to enable choosing what to process in JSF lifecyle and what to render in the end with ajax.

There are a couple of reserved keywords which serve as helpers.

-@this : Component that triggers the PPR is updated

-@parent:  Parent of the PPR trigger is updated.

-@form: Encapsulating form of the PPR trigger is updated

-@none: PPR does not change the DOM with ajax response.

-@all: Whole document is updated as in non-ajax requests.

In Partial Page Rendering, only specified components are rendered, similarly in Partial Processing 
only defined components are processed. Processing means executing Apply Request Values, 
Process Validations, Update Model and Invoke Application JSF lifecycle phases only on defined 
components.

Back to your problem, you should use  process @form

Hope this could help you.

Comment: How is using `@form` different from explicitly using the (relative) id of the form? And `@form` is the default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: @Kukeltje Both are not difference. In some case when you don't use  form's id and don't care about it, you just add attribute (prependId="false") to your form and you just add attribute (process="@form") to your submit component such as p:commandButton ... etc

Comment: if they are not different, yours will fail to. And it's best to *never* use prependId="false" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: prependId="false" is useful if you want to write javascript or css as JSF will not prefix the form id to the id you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

Add process="@this" to the commandButton.

Also, study this guide from BalusC:

[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value?rq=1)

Comment: I've tried with     <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{testCaseBean.createTestCase}" oncomplete="PF('addTestCaseDialog').hide()" process="@this, addTestCaseDialogForm"/> but it's still not working.

Comment: Study the link from BalusC.  If you process="@form" then all the fields of the form are submitted.