# context.getViewRoot().getComponentResources(context, "head"); throws nullpointer because getViewRoot() return null

Tags: primefaces

i want to use a `<p:ajax />` inside `<p:inputText></<p:inputText>` like this

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="date-form">
                                <p:inputText id="date" styleClass="form-control">
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{dashboardBean.dateChanged()}" event="change" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </h:form>
```

When the user change the date from datePicker. the bean-method `dateChanged` has to be call. but the following error is thrown instead

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/MyApp] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(ResourceUtils.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:280)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:127)
```

Trying since 3 days why the exception is thrown, need help!!!

Am using Primefaces v6.0

Comment: Tried latest PF? Looked at the PF issue list? And off-topic: don't use `prependId="false"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: I removed the `prependId`, still not working.. my pf version is 6.0

Comment: That remark was 'off-topic'

Comment: i dont really understand what u mean with 'off-topic'