# Why JSF ajax status success not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jsf

When I call an action in my ManagedBean, I also call function JS via JSF ajax to open a load popup while the action is processing as you can see in the following code. This work perfectly in firefox but not in chrome, even works in chrome (only incognito mode). I did debug via console.log and I checked that in chrome the ajax response only reachs the complete status and not success.

XHTML

```
<h:form prependId="false"> 
...
<button class="btn btn-inverse" jsf:action="#{sendSmsMB.sendSms()}">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> ENVIAR
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" onevent="ajaxLoader" />
</button>
</h:form>
```

JS

```
function ajaxLoader(data){
if(data.status == "begin"){
    $.blockUI({
        message: '<h5> <img src="../../../resources/img/loader_blue.gif" /> 
 <b>Espere que se complete el proceso de carga</b></h5>'
    });
}else if(data.status == "complete"){
    $.unblockUI();
}else if(data.status == "success"){
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

}

Comment: Might not be related but try removing the prependId: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: @Kukeltje I removed the prependId in the form but did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think that Chrome has problems with sync calls. Is your ajax call sync? If it's, try to make it async. In your ajax call, put below the data:

```
async: false
```