# JSF rendering ajax outside of form

Tags: ajax, jsf

In the following code

```
<ui:define name="left">
        <h:body>
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="first name: "/><h:inputText value="${first}" size="11"/>
                    <h:outputText value="last name: "/><h:inputText value="${last}" size="11"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="OK" id="comId" action="${squad.add(first, last)}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="custId"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ezcomp:customComponent id="custId" rendered="false" source="${squad.users}"/>
    </ui:define>
```

When i press the OK button i have the error `malformedXML: During update: custId not found`, but as i refresh the page it properly displays the data in the customCompoment. How should i fix this ?

Comment: Start by removing `prependId="false` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo

Comment: I've removed the `prependId="false"` and placed `content:custId` into render instead of `custId` since the `ui:define name="content"` has an id of `content` in the main template. Now i don't have any error message when i input that but it keeps not displaying the results until i refresh.