# JSF rendering embedded panel list ajax does not work

Tags: jsf, mojarra

I have two panels, an outer one "outer_lst_panel" and an inner one "inner_lst_panel". The inner one is embedded in the outer one. The problem is that I cannot remove an item from the inner panel. The button "Remove inner item" does not work. If I look in the generated code (see below) it seems to be a problem with the generation of a real id ("mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'inner_lst_panel')"). If I hard code

```
<h:commandButton
  value="Remove inner item"
  action="#{bean.do_delete_inner_item(mas, mav)}">
  <f:ajax render="aform:j_idt13:0:inner_lst_panel" /> <!-- Hard coded!!! -->
</h:commandButton>
```

it works. What's wrong?

JSF 2.3.2 from https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.2/javax.faces-2.3.2.jar

Bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean
...

<h:form id="aform">
  <h:panelGroup id="outer_lst_panel">
    <ui:repeat
      var="mas"
      value="#{bean.mas_lst}">Outer item
      <h:panelGroup id="inner_lst_panel">
          <ui:repeat
            var="mav"
            value="#{mas.mav_lst}">Inner item
            <h:commandButton
              value="Remove inner item"
              action="#{bean.do_delete_inner_item(mas, mav)}">
                <f:ajax render="inner_lst_panel" /> <!-- Not working!!! -->
            </h:commandButton>
          </ui:repeat>
          <h:commandButton
            value="Add inner item"
            action="#{bean.do_add_inner_item(mas)}">
            <f:ajax render="inner_lst_panel" />
          </h:commandButton>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:commandButton
        value="Remove outer item"
        action="#{bean.do_delete_outer_item(mas)}">
        <f:ajax render="aform:outer_lst_panel" />
      </h:commandButton>
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:commandButton
    value="Add outer item"
    action="#{bean.do_add_outer_item()}">
    <f:ajax render="aform:outer_lst_panel" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Generated code:

```
<form
  id="aform"
  name="aform"
  method="post"
  action="test.xhtml"
  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input
    name="aform"
    value="aform"
    type="hidden"> <span id="aform:outer_lst_panel"> Outer item <span
    id="aform:j_idt13:0:inner_lst_panel"> Inner item <input
      id="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt35:0:j_idt31"
      name="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt35:0:j_idt31"
      value="Remove inner item"
      onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'inner_lst_panel');return false"
      type="submit"><input
      id="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt42"
      name="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt42"
      value="Add inner item"
      onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'aform:j_idt13:0:inner_lst_panel');return false"
      type="submit"></span><input
    id="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt43"
    name="aform:j_idt13:0:j_idt43"
    value="Remove outer item"
    onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'aform:outer_lst_panel');return false"
    type="submit"></span><input
    id="aform:j_idt44"
    name="aform:j_idt44"
    value="Add outer item"
    onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'aform:outer_lst_panel');return false"
    type="submit"><input
    name="javax.faces.ViewState"
    id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"
    value="-2796149469970124814:8174359678892564468"
    autocomplete="off"
    type="hidden">
</form>
```

**Update:**
No, my question is not answered by [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

It's yet unclear for me why the render attribute from the ajax tag doesn't get a real reference for `inner_lst_panel` with an continual counter. From my opinion it should be rendered to

```
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'aform:j_idt13:0:inner_lst_panel')
```

but it doesn't. It becomes

```
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'inner_lst_panel')
```

and that's wrong and doesn't work.

As a workaround (no, I cannot use `render="@form"` for other reasons) I can use the following:

```
<h:form id="aform">
    <h:panelGroup id="outer_lst_panel">
        <h:panelGroup id="inner_lst_panel" binding="#{foo}">
        ...
        <f:ajax render="#{foo.clientId}" />
        ...
```

Comment: Please use attribute prependId="false" in form, it will don't general ramdom id and you must set Id for every component.

Comment: @sonpham: **DON'T** use `prependId="false"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: Please use good indentation and wrapping in your html code. The locations of the spans are difficult to find /read. Can you edit the Q?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)