# Shared template form JSF

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to share this template in multipile components in same scope? I got an error because of duplicated ID, but I need this ID for updating / processing form, also for displaying messages

```
 <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="contentForm"
                prependId="false"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:messages showDetail="true"
                        closable="true">
                <p:autoUpdate/>
            </p:messages>
                <ui:insert name="formContent" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to be 100% sure the question is really clear. Now your problem cabbot be reproduced