# PrimeFaces commandButton not work after submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following problem I have a CommandButton of primefaces that does well its function which is to save an accounting movement, but when you try to enter a second movement the button does not work to such an extent that it does not warn you if the required fields are empty.
Note that if I give the cancel button that only has a JS to hide and show some labels there is if the button works again.

I need that button to continue working without having to hit the cancel button.

I'm going to leave a partial code that includes the TAG of the form and the buttons warn if you need to also put the fields.

```
<h:form id="form_agregar_movimiento" prependId="false" >
   ...
<p:commandButton styleClass="Tamano-Texto-Datos Boton-Afirmativo" 
    value="Agregar"
    action="#{movimientosController.agregarNuevoMovimiento()}" 
    update=":growl_mensaje_eventos :dataTable_listar_movimientos form_agregar_movimiento"
    />
<p:commandButton styleClass="Tamano-Texto-Boton Boton-Negativo" 
    value="Cancelar"
    onclick="js_ocultar('agregar_movimiento_contenedor'); js_mostrar('movimiento_contenedor_botonAgregarMovimiento');"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to `update=":form_agregar_movimiento"` from inside the form or `update="@form"`.

Comment: And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Comment: hello, I have tried both methods and change the "prependId = true" and the problem follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

594/5000
Hi guys, I have solved the problem, I noticed that other forms presented the same problem and testing by ending with `@form` as recommended and the `"prependId = true"` and additional add the attribute `resetValues="true"` and with And the buttons come back to work without problems.

Note: in the example that this function did not work for me but it was for something else, I had a `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().Execute()` which calls a JavaScript and it was giving me an error in the browser, I corrected it and works correctly.
Thanks for the tips that have left me