# How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, clientid

The following code is inspired from PrimeFaces DataGrid + DataTable Tutorials and put into a `<p:tab>` of a `<p:tabView>` residing in a `<p:layoutUnit>` of a `<p:layout>`. Here is the inner part of the code (starting from `p:tab` component); the outer part is trivial.

```xml
<p:tabView id="tabs">
    <p:tab id="search" title="Search">                        
        <h:form id="insTable">
            <p:dataTable id="table" var="lndInstrument" value="#{instrumentBean.instruments}">
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandLink id="select" update="insTable:display" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lndInstrument}" 
                                        target="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{lndInstrument.name}" />
                    </p:commandLink>                                    
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:dialog id="dlg" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
                <h:panelGrid id="display">
                    <h:outputText value="Name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument.name}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>                            
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

When I click the `<p:commandLink>`, the code stops working and gives the [message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Cannot%20find%20component%20with%20expression%22%20%22referenced%20from%22):

> Cannot find component with expression "insTable:display" referenced from "tabs:insTable:select".

When I try the same using `<f:ajax>`, then it fails with a different [message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22contains%20an%20unknown%20id%22%20%22cannot%20locate%20it%20in%20the%20context%20of%20the%20component%22) basically telling the same:

> `<f:ajax>` contains an unknown id "insTable:display" cannot locate it in the context of the component "tabs:insTable:select"

When it happens during another Ajax postback and the JSF project stage is set to `Development`, then it fails with a JavaScript alert with the [message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=malformedXML%20%22during%20update%22%20%22not%20found%22):

> malformedXML: During update: insTable:display not found

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

#### Look in HTML output for actual client ID

You need to look in the generated HTML output to find out the right client ID. Open the page in browser, do a rightclick and *View Source*. Locate the HTML representation of the JSF component of interest and take its `id` as client ID. You can use it in an absolute or relative way depending on the current naming container. See following chapter.

Note: if it happens to contain iteration index like `:0:`, `:1:`, etc (because it's inside an iterating component), then you need to realize that updating a specific iteration round is not always supported. See bottom of answer for more detail on that.

#### Memorize `NamingContainer` components and always give them a fixed ID

If a component which you'd like to reference by ajax process/execute/update/render is inside the same [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) parent, then just reference its own ID.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update="result"> <!-- OK! -->
    <h:panelGroup id="result" />
</h:form>
```

If it's **not** inside the same `NamingContainer`, then you need to reference it using an absolute client ID. An absolute client ID starts with the `NamingContainer` separator character, which is by default `:`.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update="result"> <!-- FAIL! -->
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="result" />
```

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update=":result"> <!-- OK! -->
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="result" />
```

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update=":result"> <!-- FAIL! -->
</h:form>
<h:form id="otherform">
    <h:panelGroup id="result" />
</h:form>
```

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update=":otherform:result"> <!-- OK! -->
</h:form>
<h:form id="otherform">
    <h:panelGroup id="result" />
</h:form>
```

[`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) components are for example `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<p:tabView>`, `<cc:implementation>` (thus, all composite components), etc. You recognize them easily by looking at the generated HTML output, their ID will be prepended to the generated client ID of all child components. Note that when they don't have a fixed ID, then JSF will use an autogenerated ID in `j_idXXX` format. You should absolutely avoid that by giving them a fixed ID. The [OmniFaces `NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler) may be helpful in this during development.

If you know to find the javadoc of the `UIComponent` in question, then you can also just check in there whether it implements the [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) interface or not. For example, the [`HtmlForm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlForm.html) (the `UIComponent` behind `<h:form>` tag) shows it implements `NamingContainer`, but the [`HtmlPanelGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlPanelGroup.html) (the `UIComponent` behind `<h:panelGroup>` tag) does not show it, so it does not implement `NamingContainer`. [Here is the javadoc of all standard components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/package-summary.html) and [here is the javadoc of PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/).

#### Solving your problem

So in your case of:

```
<p:tabView id="tabs"><!-- This is a NamingContainer -->
    <p:tab id="search"><!-- This is NOT a NamingContainer -->
        <h:form id="insTable"><!-- This is a NamingContainer -->
            <p:dialog id="dlg"><!-- This is NOT a NamingContainer -->
                <h:panelGrid id="display">
```

The generated HTML output of `<h:panelGrid id="display">` looks like this:

```
<table id="tabs:insTable:display">
```

You need to take exactly that `id` as client ID and then prefix with `:` for usage in `update`:

```html
<p:commandLink update=":tabs:insTable:display">
```

#### Referencing outside include/tagfile/composite

If this command link is inside an include/tagfile, and the target is outside it, and thus you don't necessarily know the ID of the naming container parent of the current naming container, then you can dynamically reference it via `UIComponent#getNamingContainer()` like so:

```
<p:commandLink update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:display">
```

Or, if this command link is inside a composite component and the target is outside it:

```
<p:commandLink update=":#{cc.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:display">
```

Or, if both the command link and target are inside same composite component:

```
<p:commandLink update=":#{cc.clientId}:display">
```

See also [Get id of parent naming container in template for in render / update attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847096/get-id-of-parent-naming-container-in-template-for-in-render-update-attribute/)

#### How does it work under the covers

This all is specified as *"search expression"* in [the `UIComponent#findComponent()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-):

> A *search expression* consists of either an identifier (which is matched exactly against the id property of a `UIComponent`, or a series of such identifiers linked by the `UINamingContainer#getSeparatorChar` character value. The search algorithm should operates as follows, though alternate alogrithms may be used as long as the end result is the same:
>
> - Identify the `UIComponent` that will be the base for searching, by stopping as soon as one of the following conditions is met:
>
>   - If the search expression begins with the the separator character (called an "absolute" search expression), the base will be the root `UIComponent` of the component tree. The leading separator character will be stripped off, and the remainder of the search expression will be treated as a "relative" search expression as described below.
>   - Otherwise, if this `UIComponent` is a `NamingContainer` it will serve as the basis.
>   - Otherwise, search up the parents of this component. If a `NamingContainer` is encountered, it will be the base.
>   - Otherwise (if no `NamingContainer` is encountered) the root `UIComponent` will be the base.
> - The search expression (possibly modified in the previous step) is now a "relative" search expression that will be used to locate the component (if any) that has an id that matches, within the scope of the base component. The match is performed as follows:
>
>   - If the search expression is a simple identifier, this value is compared to the id property, and then recursively through the facets and children of the base `UIComponent` (except that if a descendant `NamingContainer` is found, its own facets and children are not searched).
>   - If the search expression includes more than one identifier separated by the separator character, the first identifier is used to locate a `NamingContainer` by the rules in the previous bullet point. Then, the `findComponent()` method of this `NamingContainer` will be called, passing the remainder of the search expression.

Note that PrimeFaces also adheres the JSF spec, but RichFaces uses ["some additional exceptions"](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Re-Rendering).

> *"reRender"* uses `UIComponent.findComponent()` algorithm (with some additional exceptions) to find the component in the component tree.

Those additional exceptions are nowhere in detail described, but it's known that relative component IDs (i.e. those not starting with `:`) are not only searched in the context of the closest parent `NamingContainer`, but also in all other `NamingContainer` components in the same view (which is a relatively expensive job by the way).

#### Never use `prependId="false"`

If this all still doesn't work, then verify if you aren't using `<h:form prependId="false">`. This will fail during processing the ajax submit and render. See also this related question: [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid).

#### Referencing specific iteration round of iterating components

It was for long time not possible to reference a specific iterated item in iterating components like `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:dataTable>` like so:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <ui:repeat id="list" value="#{['one','two','three']}" var="item">
        <h:outputText id="item" value="#{item}" /><br/>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton value="Update second item">
        <f:ajax render=":form:list:1:item" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

However, since Mojarra 2.2.5 the `<f:ajax>` started to support it (it simply stopped validating it; thus you would never face the in the question mentioned exception anymore; another enhancement fix is planned for that later).

This only doesn't work yet in current MyFaces 2.2.7 and PrimeFaces 5.2 versions. The support might come in the future versions. In the meanwhile, your best bet is to update the iterating component itself, or a parent in case it doesn't render HTML, like `<ui:repeat>`.

#### When using PrimeFaces, consider Search Expressions or Selectors

[PrimeFaces Search Expressions](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/search.xhtml) allows you to reference components via JSF component tree search expressions. JSF has several builtin:

- `@this`: current component
- `@form`: parent `UIForm`
- `@all`: entire document
- `@none`: nothing

PrimeFaces has enhanced this with new keywords and composite expression support:

- `@parent`: parent component
- `@namingcontainer`: parent `UINamingContainer`
- `@widgetVar(name)`: component as identified by given `widgetVar`

You can also mix those keywords in composite expressions such as `@form:@parent`, `@this:@parent:@parent`, etc.

[PrimeFaces Selectors (PFS)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml) as in `@(.someclass)` allows you to reference components via jQuery CSS selector syntax. E.g. referencing components having all a common style class in the HTML output. This is particularly helpful in case you need to reference "a lot of" components. This only prerequires that the target components have all a client ID in the HTML output (fixed or autogenerated, doesn't matter). See also [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

Comment: @jack: Just read javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html#SEPARATOR_CHAR Since JSF 2.0 it has become configurable instead of a constant.

Comment: Isn't *SEPARATOR_CHAR* deprecated? Can you give an example on how to call a nested component, for example: `context.getViewRoot().findComponent(":inputform"
        + UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context) + "inputtext" );` Also please include the xhtml code.

Comment: Thank you, note about failing ajax rerender inside of form with `prependId="false"` saved my day.

Comment: what is the exact meaning of __client ID__ as outlined in your explaination? Is it the same as in JSF -> "The client-side identifier for this component". regards+thanks for your work.

Comment: @BalusC: Can you suggest a solution for referencing specific iteration round of iterating components with primefaces ajax-enabled component? If i use `<p:commandButton value="Update second item" update=":form:list:1:item"/>` then `SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponents()` always transform it to `':form:list:0:item'`. I'm thinking about extending/overriding `SearchExpressionFacade` to add there additional checking for something like `update="@asis(:form:list:0:item)"`

Comment: @antonu17: As stated in the answer, it's only supported in Mojarra's f:ajax.

Comment: @BalusC: i got working variant with primefaces selectors (PFS): `<p:commandButton value="Update second item" update="@(#form\\:list\\:1\\:item)"/>`. May be its little bit ugly, but its working. :) It using jQuery selector API

Comment: @antonu17: Better use a class name. See also very bottom of answer.

Comment: Definitely avoid hard coded references to auto generated j_idt style ids such as in update.  I have found that when releasing the application onto a different server that number after j_idt can change and will therefore break the application.

Comment: All this is vaild to for the PF `process` attribute, right?

Comment: @BalusC: Do you mind if I add the new JSF2.3 keywords to this answer as well? https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1238

Answer (score 9):

first of all: as far as i know placing dialog inside a tabview is a bad practice... you better take it out...

and now to your question:

sorry, took me some time to get what exactly you wanted to implement,

did at my web app myself just now, and it works

as I sayed before place the p:dialog out side the `p:tabView ,

leave the p:dialog as you initially suggested :

```xml
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
    <h:panelGrid id="display">
        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument.name}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

and the p:commandlink should look like this (all i did is to change the update attribute)

```xml
<p:commandLink update="display" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lndInstrument}" 
        target="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{lndInstrument.name}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

the same works in my web app, and if it does not work for you , then i guess there is something wrong in your java bean code...

Comment: I recommend you to try the other changes i wrote in my answer (with the binding and faces-config and other...) this suppose to solve your "INFO: Cannot find compone..."

Comment: I have again tried to implement your 2nd suggestion, but it's still not working. The dialog opens but doesn't contain the selected item's data. The log displays "Cannot find component with identifier "j_idt31" in view", and I am not able to debug any more than this.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the tab is a naming container aswell... your update should be `update="Search:insTable:display"` What you can do aswell is just place your dialog outside the form and still inside the tab then it would be: `update="Search:display"`

Answer (score 4):

Please note that from PrimeFaces 10 and up, you are able to use observer and event.

This allows you to update components based on a custom event name, set by the `@obs(event)` keyword. For example:

```html
<p:commandButton update="@obs(myEvent)"/>

<h:panelGroup>
    <p:autoUpdate on="myEvent"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

See:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/observer.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has a great answer by BalusC but **here is a little trick I use to get the container to tell me the correct clientId**.

1. Remove the update on your component that is not working
2. Put a temporary component with a bogus update within the component you were trying to update
3. hit the page, the servlet exception error will tell you the correct client Id you need to reference.
4. Remove bogus component and put correct clientId in the original update

Here is code example as my words may not describe it best.

```
<p:tabView id="tabs">
    <p:tab id="search" title="Search">                        
        <h:form id="insTable">
            <p:dataTable id="table" var="lndInstrument" value="#{instrumentBean.instruments}">
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandLink id="select"
```

**Remove the failing update within this component**

```
 oncomplete="dlg.show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lndInstrument}" 
                                        target="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{lndInstrument.name}" />
                    </p:commandLink>                                    
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:dialog id="dlg" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
                <h:panelGrid id="display">
```

**Add a component within the component of the id you are trying to update using an update that will fail**

```
   <p:commandButton id="BogusButton" update="BogusUpdate"></p:commandButton>

                    <h:outputText value="Name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument.name}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>                            
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Hit this page and view the error.
The error is:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component for expression "BogusUpdate" referenced from 
**tabs:insTable:** BogusButton

So the correct clientId to use would then be the bold plus the id of the target container (display in this case)

```
tabs:insTable:display
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change `update="insTable:display"` to `update="display"`. I believe you cannot prefix the id with the form ID like that.

Comment: Very old but misleading answer.  Refer to BalusC's post above, clearly showing the prefixing of a component's ID with the enclosing form's ID:  <h:form id="form">
    <p:commandLink update=":otherform:result"> <!-- OK! -->
</h:form>
<h:form id="otherform">
    <h:panelGroup id="result" />
</h:form>